# c# winforms dock fill tree-view make it disappear

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application. In my application I have a user control which I loaded programmatically.

Inside this user-control I have tree view that also will be loaded with items programmatically. My problem is that I want to make my tree-view take the whole size of its parent.

**What I have tried**
I set the user-control `Dock` property to `DockStyle.Fill` to make it take the size of its parent.
I have done the same for the tree-view `Dock` property; set it to `DockStyle.Fill`.

**What I get**
The user-control takes the full size as expected **but** the tree-view looks like it is hidden. I checked the height, and I noticed it's `0`. When I tried to change the height while it has `DockStyle.Fill` I can't, it changes back to `0`.

Any ideas?
**Update**
The auto generated code for the tree-view:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.btnAddServer = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.pnlServersContainer = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
    this.treeViewServers = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
    this.pnlServersContainer.SuspendLayout();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // btnAddServer
    // 
    this.btnAddServer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 478);
    this.btnAddServer.Name = "btnAddServer";
    this.btnAddServer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 23);
    this.btnAddServer.TabIndex = 3;
    this.btnAddServer.Text = "Add New Server";
    this.btnAddServer.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.btnAddServer.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnAddServer_Click);
    // 
    // pnlServersContainer
    // 
    this.pnlServersContainer.AutoScroll = true;
    this.pnlServersContainer.Controls.Add(this.treeViewServers);
    this.pnlServersContainer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.pnlServersContainer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.pnlServersContainer.Name = "pnlServersContainer";
    this.pnlServersContainer.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 20, 0, 0);
    this.pnlServersContainer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(318, 463);
    this.pnlServersContainer.TabIndex = 2;
    // 
    // treeViewServers
    // 
    this.treeViewServers.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.treeViewServers.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 23);
    this.treeViewServers.Name = "treeViewServers";
    this.treeViewServers.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(275, 0);
    this.treeViewServers.TabIndex = 0;
    this.treeViewServers.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.treeViewServers_DoubleClick);
    // 
    // ucServersList
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.Controls.Add(this.btnAddServer);
    this.Controls.Add(this.pnlServersContainer);
    this.Name = "ucServersList";
    this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(318, 523);
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ucServersList_Load);
    this.pnlServersContainer.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

Comment: Did you mean "programmatically" instead of "problematically"? Also, do you have any other controls in your user control (except the tree view)?

Comment: i definitely like problematically more

Comment: good catch @Dennis. i only have one button

Comment: Please show the code where you added the TreeView to your form (may be in the designer.cs file)

Comment: @ebramtharwat: also, show designer-generated part of user control.

Comment: Updated my question with auto generated code

Comment: @MatthewLauser i create it using the designer then add the nodes to it programmatically

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to open `Document outline` editor in Visual Studio.
This shows all controls in their hierarchical order as tree.
It lets you also drag & drop the controls to the right place.

Open it with `View > Other windows > Document outline`.

You may fix your problem when looking at the controls order.

Comment: Thank you joe, it does not fix the problem , but you learn me something new +1

Answer (score 3):

I have figured it out. but still don't know why this happened!

my tree-view was inside `FlowLayoutPanel` not `Panel`. When i changed it to `Panel` everything goes fine. that's it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you have added several items to the same parent control, and then when you fill the parent dock with one of them, the behaviour would not be what you expect.
Use a `splitcontainer`. And when you want to fill out the dock, make sure your control belongs to two differnt panels of a `splitcontainer`.
See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) for an concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you use [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?
It seems that the `FlowLayoutPanel` does not deal with any other than `Dock.None`.

I think you should use a simple `Panel` for this application, because it does not resize the contained controls - the `Dock` property behaves as expected.
Replacing the `FlowLayoutPanel` with a `Panel` will fix your problem.

Comment: @ebramtharwat: Sound like that, eh? I just can't belive that problem and tried it out myself. I didn't know that `FlowLayoutPanel` behaves odd like this, so why not using a simple `Panel`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a super old question... but since there are no accepted answers I’ll give it a go.

This happened to me when my Control was set to autosize. Either removing autosize or specifying a minimum height could solve this issue.